# How can I solve this equation with strange powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve this:

$$ x^{a/( b-1)}c^{b/(b-1)}-j\,x-d=0 $$

where a and b are parameters and c and d just constants. As you can see, x is raised to $(a/b-1)$. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the equation?

Comment: 1. I'm not so sure that this formula goes under the definition of polynomial. 2. There is nothing to solve here (did you mean "$=0$"?).

Comment: Yes, sorry, equal to zero.

Comment: So $a,b,c$ are constant. What about $d$ and $j$? Are they also constant? Why did you choose the letter $j$? This doesn't seem like a "natural" choice, so it makes one suspicious about the "correctness" of this equation (more precisely, the "correctness" of your copy/paste operation). Where did you get it from?

Comment: Im so sorry for the confusion. d and j are also constants. I did not copy this, I am actually building a microeconomic model and I need to solve for an equation that is very non-linear. Since I chose already a,b and c, which usually are treated as constants... I ran out of the popular letters, so then just randomly chose d and j.

Comment: For the most general case, there will not be any analytical solution to this equation and only numerical methods (such as Newton) should solve the problem. You can consider that the solution corresponds to the intersection of  a straight line $y=A+B x$ and a curve $y=C x^D$. If these is one case for which you would like me to elaborate, please give me some numbers.

Comment: I was thinking of values as follow: 

a between 1/2 and 1
b between 1/10 and 1/2
c, d and j any positive number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for illustartion purposes, I used $a=\frac 34$, $b=\frac {3}{10}$ (these corresponds to the mean values of the ranges you gave in your comment), $c=2$, $d=3$, $j=4$. All of these then lead to the equation $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2^{3/7} x^{15/14}}-4 x-3=0$$ As I said in a comment, plot both functions $y=4x+3$ and $y=\frac{1}{2^{3/7} x^{15/14}}$ on the same graph. You will see that they intersect close to $x=0.2$.

Since we have a reasonable strating guess $x_0$, Newton method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For these conditions, the iterating formula will then be $$x_{n+1}=\frac{29\ 2^{4/7} x_n-84 x_n^{29/14}}{112 x_n^{29/14}+15\ 2^{4/7}}$$ and, so, starting with $x_0=0.2$, the successive iterates will then be $0.213962$, $0.214861$, $0.214864$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful

Comment: You are very welcome ! It is very simple and you will use this method a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We may write the equation as
$x^p - q x - r = 0$, where  $p = a/(b-1)$, $q = d c^{-b/(b-1)}$,  and $r = d j c^{-b/(b-1)}$.
Of course it's not a polynomial unless $p$ happens to be a nonnegative integer, and if $p > 4$ there is in general no solution in radicals.  However, there are series solutions, e.g. in powers of $t =  q r^{1/p-1}/p$:

$$x = r^{1/p} \left( 1 + t + \dfrac{3-p}{2!} t^2 + \dfrac{(4-p)(4-2p)}{3!} t^3
+ \dfrac{(5-p)(5-2p)(5-3p)}{4!} t^4 + \ldots \right)$$

which may be obtained from the Lagrange Inversion Formula.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to work this out, never heard of this method before.